# C++How does direct initialization using operator new work for the derived class with composite classes in it?

Tags: c++

I have this code. I understand that the first line of main invokes the default constructor. I dont understand how the second line works. The output should be:

```
X::X(&X) X::X(&X) X::X() Y::Y(X) X::X(&X) Z::Z(X) ~X::X()
```

It calls the explicit constructor Z(X xx) but what step it does after that?
I suppose that two first cout's related to composite classes in class Y.
The third cout is just a default c'tor of X but why it creates it and destroys it at the end?

Another question is about main's 4th line. The output should be

```
X::X() X::X() Y::Y(Y&) Z::Z(&Z)
```

here i dont understand why the the first two arent copy constructors.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
public:
    X() { cout << "X::X()" << endl; }
    X(const X& x) :t(x.t) { cout << "X::X(X&)" << endl; }
    X& operator=(const X& x) { cout << "X::op=" << endl;return *this; }
    ~X() { cout << "X::~X()" << endl; }
private:
    int t;
};

template<class T>
class Y {
public:
    Y() { cout << "Y::Y()" << endl; }
    Y(const X* pxx):x(*pxx){ cout << "Y::Y(X)" << endl; }
    Y(const T& tt):t(tt){ cout << "Y::Y(T)" << endl; }
    Y(const Y& y){ cout << "Y::Y(Y&)" << endl; }
    Y& operator=(const Y& y) { x = y.x;cout << "Y::op=" << endl;return       *this; }
    ~Y(){ cout << "Y::~Y()" << endl; }
protected:
    X x;
    T t;

};

class Z :public Y<X> {
public:
    Z() { cout << "Z::Z()" << endl; }
    Z(X xx):Y<X>(&xx), k(xx){ cout << "Z::Z(X)" << endl; }
    Z& operator=(const Z& z) { k = z.k; cout << "Z::op=" << endl; return  *this;     }
    ~Z(){ cout << "Z::~Z()" << endl; }
private:
    X k;
};

int main(){
    X* px = new X;
    Z* pzz = new Z(*px);
    Z* pz = new Z;
    Z z = *pz;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The compiler is free to make as many or as few copies as desired.  Thus you may get different output if you had optimizations turned on/off, or use a different compiler, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: That's not entirely accurate. There are certain circumstances under which the compiler is permitted to elide copies, but it isn't open season, especially when copy/move-constructors have side-effects.

Comment: If the copy constructor has side-effects, that's the programmer's issue / fault, not the compiler's.  The compiler is still free to elide copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the output step by step:

```
X::X(&X)
```

`Z`'s conversion constructor takes `xx` by value, so `X`'s copy constructor is invoked.

```
X::X(&X)
```

The `Y` conversion constructor from `const X*` copies `X` again for its member `x`.

```
X::X()
```

Since you didn't initialize `Y::t` in the initialization list, the default constructor is now called to initialize it.

```
Y::Y(X)
```

Now we reach the body of the `Y` constructor.

```
X::X(&X)
```

This is for `Z::k`

```
Z::Z(X)
```

Now we reach the `Z` constructor body

```
~X::X()
```

The copy of `X` (`xx`) created for the `Z` constructor is now destroyed.

Part 2: The line should be `X::X() X::X() Y::Y(Y&) X::X(X&)`

```
X::X()
```

Default constructor for `Y::x`

```
X::X()
```

Default constructor for `Y::t`

```
Y::Y(Y&)
```

`Y` copy constructor body

```
X::X(&X)
```

`Z::x`'s copy constructor

Surprised? The thing is the expression `Z z = *pz;` actually invokes the copy constructor for `Z`, i.e. it's no different to saying `Z z(*pz)`. You haven't defined a copy constructor for `Z`, but in this case the compiler is able to create one for you, which simply copies all bases and members.

Comment: I have one more question about the destructor ~X::X(). You said:"The copy of X created for the Z constructor is now destroyed". Is it a X::k? If it is, why it destroys it?

Comment: @Vlad That's the destructor for `xx`.